# show that $ f_h \in L^1(R) $ and $ \lim_{h \to 0} f_h(x) = f(x) $ in $ L^1(R) $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

If $ f \in L^1(R) $ and set 
$ f_h(x)= \frac{1}{2h} \int_{x-h}^{x+h}f(t)dt, h>0 $ then show that 
$ f_h \in L^1(R) $ and $ \lim_{h \to 0} f_h(x) = f(x) $ in $ L^1(R) $

To prove f_h is integrable in R we have to this integral is finite almost everywhere. I just wondering how to do that? looking for some hints

Comment: Here's some calculus-based intuition. Since $f \in L^1(\mathbb R)$, there's an $F \in L^1(\mathbb R)$ with $F' = f$ in some sense. Then compute $\|f_h\|_1 = \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{2h} \left| \int_{x-h}^{x+h} f(t) \, dt \right| \, dx = \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{\left| F(x+h) - F(x-h) \right|}{2h} \,dx \approx \int_\mathbb{R} \left| F'(x) \right| \,dx = \|f\|_1$. So we should be trying to (formally) use the Lebesgue theory to bound $\|f_h-f\|_1$ and send $h \to 0$.

Comment: @JonWarneke $F\in L^1?$

Comment: You're right, $F$ should not be $L^1(\mathbb R)$; it will eventually equal $\|f\|_1$, and this will make the integral $\|F\|_1$ infinite.

Answer (score 1):

It follows from the triangle inequality and a change of variables that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_h(x)| \, dx \leq \frac{1}{2h} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{x-h}^{x+h} |f(y)| \, dy \, dx = \frac{1}{2h} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{-h}^h |f(x+t)| \, dt \, dx.$$

Now use Tonelli's theorem to conclude $\|f_h\|_1 \leq \|f\|_1$.